# How To Filter Pandas Dataframe Ignoring Null Columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
     col1    col2    col3    col4
0    8       2       nan     nan               
1    nan     2       15      nan            
2    nan     2       15      4           
3    3       2       15      nan
```

How can I filter the dataframe to show all rows which contain matching **non-nan** values? For example if I applied the following filter...

```
     col1    col2    col3    col4             
0    nan     2       15      nan
```

...the desired output should be:

```
     col1    col2    col3    col4             
0    nan     2       15      nan            
1    nan     2       15      4           
2    3       2       15      nan
```

Comment: What is the filter you applied?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's happening with the filter, is your filter saying that you would like to select all 'nans' '2' '15' 'nans' from the respective columns?

Comment: or is it just if the row contains at least one of those values in the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I filter the dataframe to show all rows which contain matching non-nan values

You can first `dropna()` on `axis=1` to get rid of columns which has `NaN` in the filter df. Then merge;

```
print(df)
print('\n')
print(f)

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   8.0     2   NaN   NaN
1   NaN     2  15.0   NaN
2   NaN     2  15.0   4.0
3   3.0     2  15.0   NaN


   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   NaN     2    15   NaN
```

---

```
final=df.merge(f.dropna(1))
```

---

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   NaN     2  15.0   NaN
1   NaN     2  15.0   4.0
2   3.0     2  15.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `filtcol` is your filter (a dataframe with one row) and df your starting dataframe, do:

```
cols = filtcol.dropna(1).columns
ddf = df.loc[~df[cols].isna().any(axis=1)]
```

`cols` is an index holding the names of the columns in your filter whose values are not `NaN`.
`ddf` is obtained by selecting the rows in the original dataframe whose `col` column values are all not `NaN`.

`ddf` is:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
1   NaN     2  15.0   NaN
2   NaN     2  15.0   4.0
3   3.0     2  15.0   NaN
```

---

Note that this solution checks only if the value is `NaN` or not. That means that your filter can have any non NaN value, there is no need to match the exact values in the dataframe. You will get the same result even if your filter is, for example:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   NaN     0     0   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, this works also. I like the simplicity of `final=df.merge(f.dropna(1))`